# How to temporarily replace a global symbol for given call?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's assume that I have a function **foo()** which calls some library function **module.bar()**. I would like to replace **module.bar()** with **my_bar()** and then call **foo()** so, it will use **my_bar()** instead of library function.

But there is a complication:
There are other threads calling **module.bar()** so I cannot simply replace it globally: **module.bar = my_bar** because it would affect other threads which I would like to avoid.

Is there any smart solution?

Comment: *"Is there any smart solution?"* - there likely is, and what you're describing probably isn't it ;-) Can you elaborate on why you need to do something like this?

Comment: Why are you doing this? At first I thought you might be trying to replace it with a mock for unit testing, but if you have other threads running simultaneously that need the original function, it sounds like you've just written a poor API. Can you have `foo` take an argument for which library function to use, defaulting to `module.bar` but replaceable by other options?

Comment: Actually it is about testing. But not unit testing. It is heavy stability and functional test.

Comment: I thought it is possible to do something with global dictionary returned by globals(). For example transparently provide a different copy to a function or something like this.